# Swiper js: destroy и init в зависимости от ширины экрана?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему. Нужно инициализировать слайдер в зависимости от ширины экрана.
Сделала условие, поставила листинер, destroy в зависимости от ширины экрана.
Оно вроде работает, но не так как нужно. Если повторно начать ресайзить окно браузера, то destroy перестает срабатывать

```js
let mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');

mql.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.matches) {
    let newSwiper = new Swiper('.steps-slider', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      centeredSlides: false,
      spaceBetween: 8,
      grabCursor: true,
      init: true
    });
  } else {
    swiper.destroy();
  }
})
```

Comment: А если заменить на событие resize?

Answer (score 1):

```
let mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (mql.matches) {
    let newSwiper = new Swiper('.steps-slider', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      centeredSlides: false,
      spaceBetween: 8,
      grabCursor: true,
      init: true
    });
  } else {
    swiper.destroy();
  }
})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]